# [Chrome][Firefox] Is it possible to accept/decline access to media devices getUserMedia request without mouse?

Tags: google-chrome, firefox

Is it possible to accept/decline access to media devices in getUserMedia request(popup) using only keyboard (without mouse)?

The browsers I'm interested in are Chrome and Firefox.

Can't find related issues or keyboard shortcuts.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Welcome to SuperUser!

I'm not sure how you could do this programmatically, although you may be able to do it with a custom-made WebExtension. However, using the keyboard is super easy.

If you're in Firefox, when the permission popups are active, you should see that each of the buttons has an underlined letter. As a long-standing tradition in the world of PC programs, if you see an underlined letter, pressing Alt+Letter will focus or press that element, and indeed, this works in Firefox. (Tested using [permission.site](https://permission.site/))

[image: Screenshot of Firefox permission popup]

Additional info... you can press F6 or Ctrl+L to focus the address bar. From there, Shift+Tab  and Enter will open up the 'Website info' popup which is where you can view relevant certificate info and website permissions.

[image: Screenshot of address bar]

- Red Arrow (Site permissions/privacy) = F6, Shift+Tab, Enter
- Green Arrow (Certificate/security) = F6, Shift+Tab, Right, Enter